# Setting a fixed FPS on a Python 3 game

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame, frame-rate

I'm currently making a game using PyGame (Python 3), and I'm looking for a way to make the game run at a fixed FPS.

Most of the game is located inside a giant while loop, where the user input is taken, sprites are rendered, etc. every tick. My problem is that running the game on a slow computer is fine, but running it on a fast one makes the game way too fast. I can, of course, add a `time.sleep()` command at the end of the loop, but then the game will run too slow on slow computers.

Is there a way to make the loop take a specified amount of time to run through? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the clock module in pygame.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
```

Then in your main loop call this once per frame:

```
clock.tick(30) # Now your game will be capped at 30 fps
```

To read more about the clock module here is the documentation: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html